# Why uppercase for $X$ and lowercase for $y$?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, cross-validation, scikit-learn

Why is it most of the time (in many websites, articles or demonstration) the feature variable (columns) is denoted by a upper-case 'X' whereas the target variable is a lower-case 'y'?

Looks more like a coding standard to me.
Ex.

```
X = df.iloc[:, :-1]
y = df.iloc[:, -1]
```

Just curious because I hardly ever use just a single letter to represent a variable storing meaningful data.

Comment: Consistency with linear algebra notation, I guess? The features usually form a matrix (typically denoted by uppercase) whereas the labels are usually 1d, forming a column vector (typically denoted by lowercase).

Comment: "I hardly ever use just a single letter to represent a variable storing meaningful data." - the problem is that in common math typesetting, product signs are not written. Thus, it is unclear whether an expression $pi$ represents a single variable called "pi", or the product of two separate variables "p" and "i", $pi=p\times i$. To avoid this confusion, math-heavy disciplines very rarely use variables containing multiple letters. (When you implement an algorithm, yes, it is very good practice to replace single-letter variables by multi-letter ones, if only for easier search&replace.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa But in programming, a variable named `pi` does _never_ mean a product of `p` and `i` (of course, unless you write `pi = p * i` or similarly). Even in the languages that allow juxtaposition for product they will be spaced out (`p i`, for example).
(I personally think that allowing omission of the product symbol was of the strongest blunders in math notation history, since it restricts the variable name to one letter, so more or less meaningful designations are not possible without using indices; and the 1-letter names quickly run out, which forces us to use Greek, Gothic etc.)

Comment: @trolley813: the OP was explicitly asking about "websites , articles or demonstration", *not* programming - but then proceeded to noting (correctly) that this is not the convention in programming. There is simply a [category confusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake) here, which I pointed out.

Comment: See also https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/17598/55122, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52237376/10495893.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The question about why $X$ and $y$ are popular choices in mathematical notions has been answered in the [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) website: *[Why are X and Y commonly used as mathematical placeholders?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/8109/why-are-x-and-y-commonly-used-as-mathematical-placeholders)* (In short: cause [Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes) said so!)

In terms of Linear Algebra, it is *extremely common* to use capital Latin letters for matrices (e.g. design matrix $X$) and lowercase Latin letters for vectors (response vector $y$). Standard textbooks on the use of matrices in Statistics (e.g. [*Matrix Algebra Useful for Statistics*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrix-Algebra-Useful-Statistics-Probability/dp/1118935144) by Searle, [*Matrix Algebra From a Statistician's Perspective*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrix-Algebra-Statisticians-Perspective-Harville/dp/0387783563/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=67BC3NQEMH56YTVBCY39) by Harville and [*Matrix Algebra: Theory, Computations, and Applications in Statistics*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrix-Algebra-Computations-Applications-Statistics/dp/3319648667/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=67BC3NQEMH56YTVBCY39) by Gentle) utilise this convention too, so it has become a standard way to denote things.

Answer (score 7):

**Before** you collect any data values on the feature and target variables, these variables can be considered to be *random* variables provided a random mechanism will be used to select the subjects who will generate these values. In that case, the correct notation for these variables is Y and X (i.e., upper case letters for both).

Recall that the value of a random variable is *unknown* prior to collecting the data, though its behaviour in the long run can be predicted using probability laws. However, once we collect the data, that value becomes known.

**After** you collect all desired data values on the feature and target variables, you can use the lower case notation to denote the collection of data values corresponding to the target variable (y) and the feature variables (x). If you have a single feature variable, x is a vector of data values. If you have multiple feature variables, x is a matrix of data values, having one column per feature variable. Usually, y is a vector of data values.

So the *upper case* notation refers to *"random (hence unknown)"*, while the *lower case* notation refers to *"known"*. Alternatively, the *upper case* notation refers to *"before collecting the data"*, while the *lower case* notation refers to *"after collecting the data"*.

Sadly, the literature is not at all consistent in the use of this notation, which is why you see the (y,X) notation you mention in your question.

Answer (score 1):

To understand when to use lowercase or uppercase, we need to know what is represented in `X_train` or `X_test`. It is a capital letter X to represent a 2-D matrix. And for `y_train` and `y_test`, it is a small letter y to represent a 1-D vector.

Mathematically, it is a common notation for Linear Algebra to use uppercase Latin letters for matrices (e.g. matrix X) and lowercase Latin letters for vectors (vector y).

In data science, the feature matrix `X` is a collection of many columns of feature values. For example a `df` with 1 target, 20 features and 1000 data records will have the shape of shape (1000, 21). So we will define the feature matrix `X` to have the shape (1000, 20). Whereas the target label `y` is a column of values having the shape (1000, 1).

After applying `train_test_split()` on `X` and `y` with `test_size=0.25`, I would expect:
`X_train` to be a 2-D matrix (750, 20)
`y_train` to be a 1-D vector (750, 1)